# how to detect if running in osgi container

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I have an OSGi bundle that can also run in plain Java process. I need to be able to tell if the bundle was loaded in an OSGi system or not. How can I do that? If there is no OSGi-standard way of doing this, I will settle for Eclipse/Equinox-specific approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have an activator, you can also try asking for your bundle:

```
Bundle b = org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil.getBundle(MyClass.this);
```

If it returns null, your class wasn't loaded by OSGi.

Comment: How does this compare to "getClass().getClassLoader() instanceof org.osgi.framework.BundleReference" approach? Will this work on wider range of OSGi versions?

Comment: Peeking at the implementation, it depends on BundleReference as well and is available from OSGi 4.2 on (eclipse 3.5.x?).  I would recommend it over the instanceof check because it is API.

Comment: Note that the "instanceof" check is also API since the spec states that the bundle's class loader must implement BundleReference.

Comment: Wouldn't this throw a class not found exception if this code was run in a non-osgi runtime?

Answer (score 11):

Add Bundle-Activator to your MANIFEST.MF.  If it gets instantiated, then your JAR is running in an OSGi container.

Comment: Lots up votes here. Could someone explain why to the newbies?

Comment: It's a simple solution that works.  Prior to OSGi 4.2, there wasn't a convenient way to introspect a class loader to determine it's status as a bundle (PackageAdmin.getBundle is the only way).

Comment: thanks. That parenthetical comment is the (actionable) detail I think I need.

Comment: Well, to get access to PackageAdmin, you have to somehow get a BundleContext for getService, so you need a Bundle-Activator somewhere.  If you already have a Bundle-Activator in some other JAR, then yes, you can use PackageAdmin.getBundle to inspect arbitrary classes.

Comment: A Bundle-Activator requires implementing org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator that is not present in a non-osgi environment.

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether "this.getClass().getClassLoader() instanceof org.osgi.framework.BundleReference", which should only be true if you are running in an R4.2 OSGi framework.

Comment: I was working with tests in an eclipse setup and got org.eclipse.osgi as the beginning of the package of the class loader. I decided to check what the name of the class loader in the non-osgi situation is (com.sun.... I forget, now I"m at home). This leaves my test open to working in other OSGI implementations, though it's subject to other non-osgi class loader implementations being used and throwing a spanner into the works.

Answer (score 1):

An improved answer to Richard S. Hall that doesn't require a compile and runtime dependency to osgi. It also checks if the classloader of a class implements `org.osgi.framework.BundleReference` interface.

```
Class<?> classToCheck = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getClass();
boolean runningOsgi = isOsgiClassLoader(classToCheck);
...

boolean isOsgiClassLoader(Class<?> classLoaderClass) {
    Class<?> c = classLoaderClass;
    while (c != null) {
        if (c.getName().equals("org.osgi.framework.BundleReference")) {
            return true;
        }
        for (Class<?> ifc : c.getInterfaces()) {
            if (isOsgiClassLoader(ifc)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        c = c.getSuperclass();
    }
    return false;
}
```